# Alternative Solutions for matching substrings

Tags: python, pandas

Any Alternative methods to achieve this solution?
using str.contains() is not very elegant when there are many keys to match.

```
df = DataFrame({'A':['Cat had a nap','Dog had puppies','Did you see a Donkey','kitten got angry','puppy was cute']})
    dic = {'Cat':'Cat','kitten':'Cat','Dog':'Dog','puppy':'Dog'}

               A
0   Cat had a nap
1   Dog had puppies
2   Did you see a Donkey
3   kitten got angry
4   puppy was cute


df['Cat'] = (df['A'].astype(str).str.contains('Cat')|df['A'].astype(str).str.contains('kitten')).replace({False:0, True:1})
df['Dog'] = (df['A'].astype(str).str.contains('Dog')|df['A'].astype(str).str.contains('puppy')).replace({False:0, True:1})
df



    A                    Cat    Dog
0   Cat had a nap          1    0
1   Dog had puppies        0    1
2   Did you see a Donkey   0    0
3   kitten got angry       1    0
4   puppy was cute         0    1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `|` for regex `or` in [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with cast boolean to integer by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['Cat'] = df['A'].astype(str).str.contains('Cat|kitten').astype(int)
df['Dog'] = df['A'].astype(str).str.contains('Dog|puppy').astype(int)
```

Similar:

```
a = df['A'].astype(str)
df['Cat'] = a.str.contains('Cat|kitten').astype(int)
df['Dog'] = a.str.contains('Dog|puppy').astype(int)
```

---

```
print (df)
                      A  Cat  Dog
0         Cat had a nap    1    0
1       Dog had puppies    0    1
2  Did you see a Donkey    0    0
3      kitten got angry    1    0
4        puppy was cute    0    1
```

More dynamic solution with dictionary of `list`s:

```
dic = {'Cat':['Cat','kitten'],'Dog':['Dog','puppy']}
for k, v in dic.items():
    df[k] = df['A'].astype(str).str.contains('|'.join(v)).astype(int)
print (df)
                      A  Cat  Dog
0         Cat had a nap    1    0
1       Dog had puppies    0    1
2  Did you see a Donkey    0    0
3      kitten got angry    1    0
4        puppy was cute    0    1
```

Comment: Any other ways other than str.contains? @jezrael

Comment: @SharvariGc - There is some problem? One possible solution is use `df['A'].apply(lambda x: 'dog' in x)`

Comment: Thanks!. `df['A'].apply(lambda x: 'dog' in x.lower())` to be more accurate

Comment: There is no problem. Need to build  with different syntax.@jezrael